# C# mongodb driver throwing System.InvalidOperationException on linq query with OrderByDescending

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, sql-order-by

I am using the following linq query to in c# to get a list of phone numbers from the Bill Collection sorted descending in according to the date&time of the creation of the bill. But this code gives me a System.InvalidOperationException.
It works fine when i remove the Orderby clause. Any help?

```
 var result  = collection
                .AsQueryable<Bill>()
                .Where(bill => bill.customer_details.phone != null)
                .OrderByDescending(bill => bill.date_time)          
                .Select(_ => _.customer_details.phone)
                .Distinct()
                .ToList<string>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @stuartd for suggesting me to use group by.

The following code worked for me

```
var result = collection
            .AsQueryable<Bill>()
            .Where(bill => bill.customer_details.phone != null)
            .OrderByDescending(bill => bill.date_time)
            .GroupBy(bill => bill.customer_details.phone)
            .Select(bill => bill.First().customer_details.phone)
            .ToList<string>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Isn't each item of collection unique? Do you really need `Distinct`? Although I do not have your data collection, I think `Distinct` is messing up the order. Try to omit `Distinct` or `OrderByDescending`

Comment: This is not an answer and should be a comment.

Comment: Part of my answer can be as comment, sure, but the final part might be the solution.

Comment: Yeah I want distinct data.  phone_numbers are not unique

Comment: But why do you order it when you distinct them later...? The distinct removes the repeating items. So the ordering before distincting does not make a sense, does it?

Comment: The distinct isn't going to do anything, assuming there's some kind of Id in the Bill class

Comment: I need the phone numbers in descending order of the creation of the bill
Distinct removes the repeating items but does not order them

Comment: @stuartd I need distinct phone_numbers not distinct bills

Comment: @RitwikBhar Distinct removes identical **rows**. As the `Id` or `date_time` would be different in each row, there are no duplicate rows. Perhaps you should use the equivalent of  `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @stuartd Thank You!! I thought distinct works on the projected field.
Group By worked for me. :)